# Checkboard like layout CSS JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I need a checkboard layout to display elements, i.e. the individual elements are displayed in the layout in two colors like a chessboard.
The elements come from a CMS and the editor is required to insert the elements so that the colored layout fits (colors always alternate). The editor gives each element a background color.
A case here is that in the desktop view a 4 checkboard is displayed. In a mobile view, however, the checkboard is supposed to wrap and wrap to a 3 checkboard. This also works, however this has the consequence that as in the attached picture the change of the colors is no longer correct. Is there a way to use Css(SCSS, e.g. with Order) to make it reasonable to rearrange the elements?

[image]

Here a short code snipped:
html:

```
<section class="checkboard-container">
 <div class="element"/>
  <div class="element"/>
  ....
</section>
```

css:

```
.checkboard-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-items: wrap;
  Align-items: stretch;
}

.element {
 flex-basis: 25%;
 min-width: 25%;
 padding: 0;
 
 @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
   flex-basis: 33%;
   min-width: 33%;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, if you are only concerned with the background color and not the content of the elements then you can utilize media queries to change the background color of the present elements to keep the checkered effect consistent on desktop and mobile.

```css
section {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
}

/* 4 column colouring */
div:nth-child(8n+1), div:nth-child(8n+3), div:nth-child(8n+6), div:nth-child(8n+8) {background-color:black;}
div:nth-child(8n+2), div:nth-child(8n+4), div:nth-child(8n+5), div:nth-child(8n+7) {background-color:gray;}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    div {width:33%;background-color: black;}
    div:nth-child(6n+1),div:nth-child(6n+3), div:nth-child(6n+5) {background-color:black;}
    div:nth-child(6n+2), div:nth-child(6n+4), div:nth-child(6n+6) {background-color:gray;}
}
```

```html
    <section>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </section>
```

SCSS version:

```
    /* 4 column colouring */
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    &:nth-child(8n+1),&:nth-child(8n+8),&:nth-child(8n+3),&:nth-child(8n+6),&:nth-child(8n+8) {
        background-color: black;
    }
    &:nth-child(8n+2),&:nth-child(8n+5),&:nth-child(8n+7),&:nth-child(8n+4) {
        background-color: gray;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    div {
        width: 33%;
        background-color: black;
        &:nth-child(6n+1),&:nth-child(6n+3),&:nth-child(6n+5) {
            background-color: black;
        }
        &:nth-child(6n+2),&:nth-child(6n+6),&:nth-child(6n+4)  {
            background-color: gray;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you start by setting mobile view, then desktop view (`@media screen and (min-width: 800px)`) you won't need `!important`.

Comment: @Cédric actually we don't need important in either case as the responsive query is under the default CSS rules so it overwrites the default rules, I have edited the answer and removed unnecessary "!important". but mobile-first design is indeed a better approach.

Comment: Thank you a very lot! This is doing the trick! :) 
Unfortunately im not that good with the "nth-child" magic, could you provide another short example for a 2 column case? So the colors should be something like:
black grey grey black black grey grey black black
and so on? Thanks alot!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you! 
Here is the code for 2 column checkboard.
`@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* 2 column colouring */
    div {width:50%;background-color: black !important;}
    div:nth-child(4n+1), div:nth-child(4n+4) {background-color:black !important;}
    div:nth-child(4n+2), div:nth-child(4n+3) {background-color:gray !important;}
}` @Alex